# Login in android app using php and mysql database

Tags: java, php, mysql, android-studio, android-asynctask

I'm trying to login with four different users using php and mysql database in android, and after if any user login with email and password i'm trying to fetch their information like (Name, Address, ID, etc.) from mysql database.
And i want that whenever if any of user from those four users login they can able to see their own information from database like(Name, Address, ID, etc.)

I have already tried to separate those users with the user type and with if-else condition that is in code that i provided.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG="LoginActivity";

    private TextView createaccount;
    private EditText Ausername,Apassword;
    private Button LoginButton;
    private Context mContext;


    //URLS class
    //ALL URLs
    URLs urLs;




    RelativeLayout relativeLayout1,relativeLayout2;
    Handler handler=new Handler();
    Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            relativeLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            relativeLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        urLs = new URLs();


        if (SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).isLoggedIn()){

            finish();
            Intent intentD = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentD);
        }

        relativeLayout1 = findViewById(R.id.rel3);
        relativeLayout2 = findViewById(R.id.rel2);
        Ausername = findViewById(R.id.etuname);
        Apassword = findViewById(R.id.etpass);
        LoginButton = findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
        createaccount = findViewById(R.id.tvregistration);

        createaccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Rigistration_Option.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });


        LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                userLogin();


            }
        });
    }
        private void userLogin(){
            //first getting the values
            final String email = Ausername.getText().toString();
            final String password = Apassword.getText().toString();

            //validating inputs
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Ausername.setError("Please enter your username");
                Ausername.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Apassword.setError("Please enter your password");
                Apassword.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

            //if everything is fine

            class UserLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

                ProgressBar progressBar;

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                    super.onPostExecute(s);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                    try {
                        //converting response to json object
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

                        //if no error in response
                        if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            //getting the user from the response
                            JSONObject userJson = obj.getJSONObject("user");

                            //creating a new user object
                            CA_SIGNUP_GTST user = new CA_SIGNUP_GTST(
                                    userJson.getInt("id"),
                                    userJson.getString("name"),
                                    userJson.getString("email"),
                                    userJson.getString("mobile"),
                                    userJson.getString("address")
                            );

                            //storing the user in shared preferences
                            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(user);

                            //starting the profile activity
                            finish();

                            Intent intentD = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intentD);

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                    //creating request handler object
                    RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

                    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

                    URLs urLs = new URLs();

                    if (urLs.equals("cma_login")) {

                        params.put("email", email);
                        params.put("password", password);

                        return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URLs.CMA_LOGIN, params);
                    }

                    else if (urLs.equals("ca_login")){

                        params.put("email", email);
                        params.put("password", password);

                        return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URLs.CA_LOGIN, params);

                    }

                    else if (urLs.equals("cs_login")){

                        params.put("email", email);
                        params.put("password", password);

                        return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URLs.CS_LOGIN, params);

                    }
                    else if (urLs.equals("adv_login")){

                        params.put("email", email);
                        params.put("password", password);

                        return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URLs.ADV_LOGIN, params);

                    }


                    return null;
                }
            }

            UserLogin ul = new UserLogin();
            ul.execute();
        }
    }
```

i expect that after user login they can see their own information but when i try to login with second and the third user then they are unable to login.

Comment: What is your exact problem? This is not a "implement my requirements" platform.